# Cannot use Login as Member for another Super Admin

Tags: control-panel

EE 2.8.1 - when I try to login as a member (another Super Admin) and check the radio button for go to CP (or any button or none) EE just logs me out and dumps me back on the login screen.

Anyone have a similar issue or suggest a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix for this: turns out it was the CP url in the config file was wrong! Doh!